# Solving Two sum: NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python

The problem statement : Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

My solution(trying to do better than bruteforce approach):

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        if (target - nums[i]) in nums.remove(nums[i]):  #error
            if i != nums.index(target - nums[i]):
                return i, nums.index(target - nums[i])
```

I keep getting `Line 9: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` .

I believe`.remove()` returns a list and I am trying to check if `target - nums[i]` is in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`remove()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_remove.htm) returns `None`. Try this instead:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        nums.remove(nums[i])
        if (target - nums[i]) in nums:
            if i != nums.index(target - nums[i]):
                return i, nums.index(target - nums[i])
```

Alternately, if you need to maintain `nums`, make a copy and remove:

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type target: int
    :rtype: List[int]
    """
    for i in range(0,len(nums)):
        nums_copy = list(nums)
        nums_copy.remove(nums[i])
        if (target - nums[i]) in nums_copy:
            if i != nums.index(target - nums[i]):
                return i, nums.index(target - nums[i])
```

Comment: why didn't you do `nums_copy = nums` and explicitly converted `nums` to list?

Comment: That's not a copy, that is just a pointer to the original nums. To copy a list you need to take an extra step. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list) question.

Answer (score 0):

`a.remove()` doesn't return a list. It returns `None`

```
>>> a_list = [1, 2]
>>> print(a_list.remove(1))
None
>>> print(a_list)
>>> [2]
```

As the error message suggest to iterate an object you need an object which is iterable.